# Kivy App not responding on android

Tags: android, python, kivy, logcat, kivy-language

Kivy version 1.10
Python 2.7.12

Kivy App UI on android freeze shows application not responding.

Logcat :

```
05-12 15:48:54.915  1267  1323 E ActivityManager: ANR in org.test.troubleshoot:python (org.test.troubleshoot/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity)
05-12 15:48:54.915  1267  1323 E ActivityManager:   2.7% 27081/org.test.troubleshoot:python: 1.5% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 54 minor
05-12 15:51:42.607  1267  1323 E ActivityManager: ANR in org.test.troubleshoot:python (org.test.troubleshoot/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity)
05-12 15:51:42.607  1267  1323 E ActivityManager:   3.2% 27081/org.test.troubleshoot:python: 2.1% user + 1% kernel / faults: 4 minor
05-12 15:52:42.852  1267  1323 E ActivityManager: ANR in org.test.troubleshoot:python (org.test.troubleshoot/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity)
05-12 15:52:42.852  1267  1323 E ActivityManager:   2.8% 27081/org.test.troubleshoot:python: 1.8% user + 1% kernel / faults: 309 minor
05-12 15:53:38.713  1267  1323 E ActivityManager: ANR in org.test.troubleshoot:python (org.test.troubleshoot/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity)
05-12 15:53:38.713  1267  1323 E ActivityManager:   2.9% 27081/org.test.troubleshoot:python: 1.6% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 197 minor
```

Any suggestion to avoid these faults.

Comment: Is this an application you built yourself or is it an app that you use?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE : We created this app, sometimes it crashes with these logs